# Creating N identical arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays

So, I'm trying to create `n` identical arrays of the same size but with a slightly different name.

I cannot just define them individually as `n` depends on an input.
The only way I could think to do this is using a for loop, as shown below:

```
i=0;
for (j=0;j<n;j++){
   int array_i[256];
   i=i+1;
}
```

I was wondering if there's a way of allowing `i` to update name of `array_i`?
Or if there is just a better method to do this?

Thanks for any help

Comment: It looks like what you really want is to have an array of arrays. In any case, you can't do what you want the way you want.

Comment: That's what 2-D arrays are for. Why do you want your arrays to have names? It's not that somebody will read it like a novel, you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do it is by using a 2-dimensional array.

How to work with it:

```
int i, j; //counters
int array[n][256];

for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<256; j++) {
        //enter code for element array[i][j] here
    }
}
```

Comment: The arrays have to be allocated dynamically. `n` depends on user input.

Comment: This is correct in C99, however it is susceptible to bloat stack usage very quickly as n rows. See my answer for another alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `##` operator which can paste two tokens together to form a single token, but not a good choice.

```
#define MAKE_ARR(n) array_##n  
int MAKE_ARR(1)[256], MAKE_ARR(2)[256];
```

After preprocessing:

```
 int array_1[256], array_2[256];
```

Comment: Attention ! with this construction you can't use MAKE_ARR(i) as requested. This won't be dynamic.

Comment: But this is just the same as naming them `array1`, `array2`, etc.

Comment: @zubergu; Suppose you want to write a single function that returns max of two generic types. How would you write that? The easy way you can proceed is to write macro. `#define GEN_MAX(type) type type##_max(type a, type b){return a > b ? a : b }`. That's it.

Comment: @zubergu; Nothing except if you are learning how to perform token-pasting :)

Comment: @zubergu; Sorry, I am taking my words back. `array_1[0]` will [work](http://ideone.com/xtFdIQ).

Comment: @haccks It seems so obsious...now.

Comment: @zubergu; Learned something new today :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a dynamic array to static arrays of size 256. Since you don't know in advance how many arrays there is you'll have to allocate them dynamically. Here is how you could do it.

```
int (*arrays)[256];
unsigned int i;

/* Reserve space for n arrays of 256 int elements */
arrays = malloc(sizeof(int) * 256 * n);  /* or calloc() if you want it zeroed out */

/* Now you can access your arrays as if it was a normal 2D array */
arrays[i][j] = 42;
```

If and only if you can afford to use C99 variable lengths array, this is also possible :

```
 int arrays[n][256];
```

Keep in mind that it will eat `n * 256 * sizeof(int)` bytes on the stack, so unless  you can guarantee that n is a very small number (like 2 or 3) it is probably a bad idea to reserve that much space on the stack, doing it with malloc is cleaner/safer.